# How to avoid the validation, callbacks and 'attr_accessible' effects during the seeding process using Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, seed

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to seed data in my application database.

In 'RAILS_ROOT/models/user.rb' I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible #none

  validates :name,
    :presence => true
  validates :surname,
    :presence => true
  validates :email,
    :presence => true
end
```

In 'RAILS_ROOT/db/seeds.rb' I have:

```
# Test 1
User.find_or_create_by_email (
  :name       => "Test1 name",
  :surname    => "Test1 surname",
  :email      => "test1@test1.test1"
)

# Test2
User.find_or_create_by_email (
  :name       => "",
  :surname    => "",
  :email      => "test2@test2.test2"
)
```

So, running in the Terminal

```
rake db:seed
```

of course the database will NOT populate with datas because 'attr_accessible' to nil (Case Test1) and validation not passed (Case Test2).

*I would like to skip the validation and "attr-accessible effects" during the seeding process.* **Is it possible? If so, how to do that?**

P.S.: I don't want to use in 'RAILS_ROOT/db/migrate/201....rb' code like this:

```
execute "INSERT INTO users ( name, surname, email ) VALUES ( "Test1 name", "Test1 surname", "test1@test1.test1")"
```

---

**UPDATE**

I need also to *skip all callbacks*. **Is it possible? If so, how?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check [ActiveRecord's documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes%3D) you'll see the `attributes=` method has a parameter to enable this:

`attributes=(new_attributes, guard_protected_attributes = true)`

Use it like this:

```
# Create a new user
@user = User.new

# Attributes for the user
@attrib = {
  :name       => "Test1 name",
  :surname    => "Test1 surname",
  :email      => "test1@test1.test1"
}

# Use 'send' to call the attributes= method on the object
@user.send :attributes=, @attrib, false

# Save the object
@user.save
```

---

Comment: I need also to skip all callbacks. Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah. Do `@user.send :create_without_callbacks` insted of `@user.save`

Comment: Sorry, that method only works on rails 2, apparently. Haven't used it yet on rails 3 and from what I'm searching it seems it's not available.

Comment: I am looking on internet and I found all solutions that don't work. They are: '@user.after_create.clear' (from http://blog.viarails.net/2009/1/29/disabling-callbacks-in-an-activerecord-data-migration) and that @tomeduarte says. So, my seed is "impossible"?!

Comment: I found an approach that works skipping all callbacks, validations and attr_accessible. It consist on redeclaring the ActiveRecord class in the 'seed.rb' file in order to override (here I am not sure) all statements in the RoR application related to that ActiveRecord. Example: class User < ActiveRecord::Base ... end. Just add that code in 'seed.rb'.

Comment: It's best if you post your solution as an answer and accept that instead.

Comment: @user502052 thanks for sharing this. At the end, it is a PORO and you can also create the relationships if you need. Something like `class User < ActiveRecord::Base; has_many :posts; end`