# Bypass attr_accessible in seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I cannot really find a clean way to bypass attr_accessible when creating seed data. I would like to be able to use mass assignment without any problems, since i know that this seed file is totally safe.

Is there a clean way to force Rails 3 to accept those ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838716/how-to-avoid-the-validation-callbacks-and-attr-accessible-effects-during-the

Comment: i've seen it and i think i also tried it in the past. I couldn't get it to work in Rails 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#in model
attr_accessible :name, :role,.... :as => :seed

#in seed.rb
model.assign_attributes({name: "Putin", role: "president"....},:as => :seed)
model.save
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a quick hack (thanks Mike), put this at the top of your seeds.rb:

```
# Dodge the mass assignment
User.send(:attr_accessible, :username)
User.send(:attr_accessible, :admin)
```

Now you can call this with ease without cluttering up your model (using :as => :seed):

```
@user = User.find_or_create_by_username(:username => 'ryanonrails', :admin => true)
```

Comment: This is awesome as the ":as => :seed" doesn't work when using find_or_create_by!