# Preparing seed data as JSON or for Rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to prepare a rather large amount of seed data for a Rails application. Based on my limited experience, I know of two ways to do it but want to know which offers the most flexibility.

One, I could do it with Rails and just prepare the seed data the way it's used in the seeds.rb file

```
User.create!( name: "John" )
```

Or, I could create a json document of the data. For example, I know that Mongodb lets you import json documents directly into the database. I'm not sure about other databases...

It occurred to me that a json document might be the most flexible, because I suppose you could also use a regular expression script to turn the json into something like this  `User.create!( name: "John" )`

However, I'm wondering if there's any other issues I should consider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue to consider is that you can't always pass all the parameters through the constructor. Consider this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :role

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :role, presence: true

  attr_accessible :name
end
```

If you have something like `User.create({name: 'John', role: 'admin'})`, then your seed will fail because role will not be able to be assigned.

Comment: thanks, in that situation, would it be an easy fix just to add :role to attr_accessible, and then remove it after the seed?

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to do that. One way would be to say `attr_accessible :name, :role, as: :admin` and then do `User.new({role: :admin}, as: :admin)`. Another way is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838716/how-to-avoid-the-validation-callbacks-and-attr-accessible-effects-during-the

Answer (score 2):

I'm a StackOverflow newbie, so can't reply to the comments above.

I've been trying to do something similar, the mass assignment protection issue came up for me. An idea that I came across in my research was to use:

```
without_protection: true
```

I found this worked using rails 3.2.3 For example:

```
json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(File.read('db/seeds/data.json'))
json.each do |a|
     Country.create!(a['data'], without_protection: true)
end
```

See http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/401-How-to-seed-your-database-with-JSON-YAML-data-in-Rails